# How to change style of text in the middle of the element

Tags: c++, text, sfml, textstyle

How can I change the style of text in the middle of a text element? For example if I want the first half of the text to be bold but the second half not to be bold.

Comment: Use separate variables. One which is bold and one which isn't.

Comment: @itachi said it all. You can use, or get inspiration from, some tools such as https://github.com/Skyrpex/RichText

Answer (score 2):

SFML doesn't have that kind of functionality by itself.
You probably will have to split up your text into multiple `sf::Text` and position them appropriately.

Or you could [Make your own text class](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/graphics-text.php#making-your-own-text-class) which renders text like you want it to